# Azure VM Windows Server 2016 - 28GB RAM, only 2GB available

Tags: azure, memory, windows-server-2016

I can't figure out why I only have 2GB usable, when our subscription is DS12_v2 "memory optimized" plan with 28GB of RAM.  Obviously I am running into performance issues with this small amount of memory. What am I missing? [screenshot of System panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ5LC.jpg)

Comment: I recently experienced a similar issue with an Azure VM (`F4s` size).  8GB, but only 2GB is available (https://i.imgur.com/DSuxLqV.png).  I submitted a support ticket but after three calls, each an hour in duration, I gave up and decided it would be faster to just provision a new machine.  Can you check if your machine is also showing the difference in memory as "hardware reserved", as shown in my screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I just deployed a DS12_V2 in South Central US and it shows all 28GB of RAM available.  Are you running SQL on this box?  What Apps are you running or is this a new VM?

One thing you can try is to redepoy to see if getting a new host helps.  Under the Support + Troubleshooting section you will find redeploy.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/redeploy-to-new-node-windows